# Javascript Change div dimensions dynamically

Tags: javascript

I apologize as I know this is a duplicate question, but I have searched all I can and tried everything I found and nothing seems to be working. What I am trying to do is dynamically allocate a div in my html document, and then fill it with a google visualization chart.

I have all of this working properly, except for one thing. I can't make the damn dimensions of the div increase! Here is my code:

```
var thisDashboard = document.createElement(chartDivID);
thisDashboard.setAttribute("style", "width: 1000 px; height 425 px;");
thisDashboard.setAttribute("id", chartDivID);
//thisDashboard.style.height = 425 + "px";
//thisDashboard.style.width = "1000px";
document.getElementById("chartArea").appendChild(thisDashboard);

var thisChart = document.createElement(chartDivID + "_chart");
thisChart.setAttribute("style", "height: 300 px; width: 100%");
thisChart.setAttribute("id", chartDivID + "_chart");
//thisChart.style.height = 300 + "px";
//thisChart.style.width = 100 + "%";
thisDashboard.appendChild(thisChart);
```

As you can see I have tried every combination I can think of between using .setAttribute and .style.width and .style.height. For some reason it just wont work. This is the chart area div:

```
<div id="chartArea" style="width: 100%"></div>
```

I am able to make elements that were hidden appear in the newly created div, but the width just wont change! Am I missing something incredibly obvious here?

Comment: Can you show this in action, with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo? Because that looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

`width: 100%` should work, but it means that div takes all the place in width it can, so if it's for example in the table column, which's width is smaller, the div wouldn't expand it, just fit in it :)

Comment: It seems that the problem is actually on google's end. For some reason it is creating a div called "ltr" which is only 400px wide. I have no idea why that is, I think this is a question for the google visualization forums. Is there a way to close this question?

Comment: I think you can just leave it as it is, so maybe somebody will answer to it later, and others who'll come to the same problem will be able to find a solution :)